# How can I send a virtual camera to Genymotion or Android Studio Emulator in Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-emulator, genymotion

I created a virtual camera using v4l2loopback and ffmpeg. The command I use for ffmpeg is:
ffmpeg -re -l oop 1 -i vin.png -vf format=yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video2

vin.png is the image I want to stream to the webcam and /dev/video2 is the virtual webcam I created with v4l2loopback.
The virtual webcam works and I can see it e.g. with [onlinemicetest.com/webcam-test](http://onlinemicetest.com/webcam-test).
I'm using the Genymotion emulator with the newest Android API (I tried 7.0, 8.1 and 10.0) on Ubuntu 20.40.
Genymotion detects the virtual camera but only displays a dummy image:
[Wrong dummy Image from Genymotion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1SvH.jpg)
I also tried (and would prefer to use) the android studio emulator. But I can only select Webcam0 in the configuration of the device camera and that points to the real integrated camera and not to my virtual webcam.

I don't need to use ffmpeg, but I do need to use a tool that lets me control which image to stream from the command line.

Is there a way to solve this? Many thanks in advance!

Update 17.11.2020:
The Genymotion support answered me, that they plan to support virtual cameras in the future. They might be ready to add this in mid 2021.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.bluestacks.com/

Comment: Bluestacks does not work on linux unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using OBS and Android Emulator:

1. follow this tutorial: https://blog.jbrains.ca/permalink/using-obs-studio-as-a-virtual-cam-on-linux
2. use these commands to change your obs scenes: https://gist.github.com/nooitaf/9aabf72d00e16a61ea301c69ff38d804
3. check which /dev/video you are using: v4l2-ctl --list-devices
4. check which webcam is linked to that video in your avd: ./emulator -avd Pixel2 -webcam-list
5. use that webcam to start emulator from command line: ./emulator -avd Pixel2 -camera-back webcam2

Answer (score 1):

1, Edit the picture with 640*480 format, and generate the streaming "
ffmpeg -re -l oop 1 -i 640*480.png -vf format=yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video0".

2, Now the genymotion camera setting display OK.

3, But it still can't take picture from the virtual camera, :(.

[genymotion virtual camera test with 640*480 Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fOgg.jpg)

[error in take picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA1Vq.jpg)

Comment: Maybe genymotion only match the specific format streaming, for 640*480 displays good.

Comment: how to expand the resolution? 640x480 it is very very poor quality. How to expand to 720p at least?

Answer (score 0):

You can't: Genymotion does not support virtual cameras. See https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002734498-My-webcam-does-not-work-with-Genymotion-Desktop

Comment: But I actually got this to work in Windows using manycam...

Comment: @ykasur can you refer me a link how you got it to work?