# How to get an Android Virtual Device to recognise a OBS virtual camera in Linux?

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, ubuntu, obs

I'm trying to test an Android app that makes use of OpenCV for object detection. I have an Android virtual device (AVD) in Android Studio (on Ubuntu) - this device can use a webcam as a camera, and it works fine.

To speed up testing, I've recorded all of the objects using the webcam - these recordings are in MP4 files that I've imported into OBS 26.1.1 (which adds Virtual Camera support for Linux/Ubuntu). If I go into OBS, and click "Start Virtual Camera", I can view the video on the virtual camera - this virtual webcam is working as expected in Slack, Cheese (the Gnome webcam app), and [Webcam Tests](https://webcamtests.com/)

If I check video4linux, I get:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
  OBS Virtual Camera (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
      /dev/video0
```

If I then check my AVD, I get:

```
$ emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_30 -webcam-list                               
  List of web cameras connected to the computer:
  Camera 'webcam0' is connected to device '/dev/video0' on channel 0 using pixel format 'YUYV'
```

So (to me) it looks like the AVD is using the OBS virtual camera (`/dev/video0`). However, If I then start the AVD (using the command: `emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_30 -camera-back webcam0 -camera-front none`) and then try to use the camera app (the standard camera app, not my OpenCV one), I get the following warning in the terminal:

```
emulator: WARNING: _camera_client_query_stop: Camera '/dev/video0' is not started
emulator: WARNING: _camera_client_query_stop: Camera '/dev/video0' is not started
```

The camera app then closes after the warnings are output. No other camera-based app (in the AVD) is able to show the output of the virtual camera.

I managed to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65072068/13296826) answer to a similar Stack Overflow question (about AVD with OBS) - however, this answer was from a few weeks before OBS added in virtual webcam support. When I get to Step 4 of this answer, I get the following error:

```
$ emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_30 -webcam-list
  emulator: ERROR: _camera_device_open: Camera '/dev/video0' is not a video capture device
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue with the virtual webcam not functioning properly with AVD? I've attached the AVD config for additional info:

```
AvdId=Pixel_4_API_30
PlayStore.enabled=true
abi.type=x86
avd.ini.displayname=Pixel 4 API 30
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
disk.dataPartition.size=6G
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile=
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot=no
fastboot.forceColdBoot=no
fastboot.forceFastBoot=yes
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.arc=false
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.camera.back=webcam0
hw.camera.front=emulated
hw.cpu.arch=x86
hw.cpu.ncore=4
hw.dPad=no
hw.device.hash2=################# REMOVED #################
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
hw.device.name=pixel_4
hw.gps=yes
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.gpu.mode=auto
hw.initialOrientation=Portrait
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.lcd.density=440
hw.lcd.height=2280
hw.lcd.width=1080
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.ramSize=1536
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.trackBall=no
image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86/
runtime.network.latency=none
runtime.network.speed=full
sdcard.size=2048 MB
showDeviceFrame=yes
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.name=pixel_4
skin.path=/home/chardeemacdennis/Android/Sdk/skins/pixel_4
tag.display=Google Play
tag.id=google_apis_playstore
vm.heapSize=1024
```