# Unable to feed Virtual Camera into Android Emulator using Webcamoid and OBS Studio on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, android-emulator, virtual-webcam, obs-studio

I am trying to feed a recorded video into Android Emulator using virtual camera by Webcamoid. I am using Webcamoid 8.6.1. I have also tried using OBS Studio [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65072068/1355722). I can see the virtual camera footage in softwares like Zoom, but the android emulator doesn't seem to find the virtual webcam.

This is the output I am getting from the following commands.

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
vc1 (out) (platform:akvcam-2):
    /dev/video2

vc1 (platform:akvcam-3):
    /dev/video3

OBS Virtual Camera (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
    /dev/video4

USB Camera: USB Camera (usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4.3):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1

$ ./emulator -webcam-list
ERROR   | _camera_device_open: Camera '/dev/video2' is not a video capture device
List of web cameras connected to the computer:
 Camera 'webcam0' is connected to device '/dev/video0' on channel 0 using pixel format 'YUYV'
```

`vc1` was created inside Webcamoid. I was expecting it or the one created by OBS Studio to show up as `webcam1` or `webcam2`.