# Android AVD with 'emulated' camera shows no camera at all

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera, android-virtual-device

I'm emulating Android with `avdmanager` and `emulator`, and I find that when I configure a camera as `emulated`, no camera control appears in the emulator. However, I do get a camera control when I set the camera to `virtualscene`.

What do I need to do to get an 'emulated' camera? I'd like to be able to specify an image (but not have to navigate through a virtual machine in order to place that image into my camera, as 'virtualscene' requires of me). I don't have Android Studio installed, just the command line tools.

This is the relevant part of my avd's config file (`~/.android/avd/y.avd/config.ini`):

```
hw.camera.back = virtualscene
hw.camera.front = emulated
```

In this example, I've emulated a Pixel C with Android API 30 Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86.

You can see a camera menu item in this image, which represents my 'virtualscene' config.
[image: Camera control is present]

You can see NO camera menu item in this image, which represents my 'emulated' config.
[image: Lacking camera control]

Comment: Related: [How can I send a virtual camera to Genymotion or Android Studio Emulator in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65007357/295004)

Comment: Thanks, Morrison, but that content isn't related enough to be of use. Its focus is streaming, and half of the conversation is for Genymotion.

Comment: I was referencing the OBS variation. See other answer to: [Android emulator camera custom image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13818389/295004) for static image.

Answer (score 0):

My emulator's menu also does not show the camera setting. I was able to gain control over the camera emulation via command-line arguments. First, I had the emulator list the possible values with `-webcam-list` (they do not necessarily match the system's numbering). Then I chose the appropriate video device with `-camera-back webcam1`. Whether the device is a real world camera or a virtual camera (e.g. `v4l2loopback`) fed by OBS or ffmpeg (e.g. `ffmpeg -hide_banner -loop 1 -r 10 -i image.png -filter:v format=yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video1`) is up to you.

Side-note `-help-camera-front` also mentions a video playback feature, but I could not make it work.